# Apache ANT Exec - Handle exec/CakePHP Console Prompts

Tags: java, php, apache, cakephp, ant

I am fairly new to ANT but so far was able to automate majority of my tasks. I am struggling in one part and could use your help.

I have a exec task as described below:

```
$ /cakeapp/app/Console/cake schema create -s 1

<exec executable="/cakeapp/app/Console/cake">
    <arg value="schema" />
    <arg value="create" />
    <arg value="-s" />
    <arg value="1" />
</exec>
```

The problem is... the cake command above has an internal prompt. it asks

```
 [exec] Are you sure you want to create the table(s)? (y/n) 
 [exec] [y] >
```

So, I need to pass an answer (y or no) for that prompt. How can I do that using Apache ANT?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing in inputstring like this:

```
<exec executable="/cakeapp/app/Console/cake" inputstring="y" failonerror="true">
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip Vinay. The problem is the console is dynamic in nature... so I need to be able to handle multiple prompts. I found a solution using PHP, but does apache ant already has a way to handle multiple prompts for exec processes?

Comment: You can refer to this link to add condition based exec flow, You can adapt logic from it.: http://jaysonlorenzen.wordpress.com/2010/03/10/apache-ant-if-else-condition-without-ant-contrib/